# Adobe LiveCycle xfa.sourceSet errors

Tags: javascript, database-connection, livecycle, xfa

I've created a dynamic form in LiveCycle ES2 which is attempting to draw data from an Access database. The connection has been set up correctly in the Data View tab under the name "SpecsIn." I've done a lot of research through Adobe's website and other tutorials and could not find an answer to why my xfa.sourceSet packet seems to have no nodes.

The following standard loop to find the named data connection fails with an index out of bounds error.

```
var nIndex = 0;
while(xfa.sourceSet.nodes.item(nIndex).name != "SpecsIn"){nIndex++;}
```

Attempting to reference the node directly (ie `xfa.sourceSet.SpecsIn` or `xfa.sourceSet.items(0)`) results in "Invalid property get operation; packet doesn't have property 'SpecsIn'" (or items). I've also tried using the `xfa.resolveNodes()` function with no success.

`xfa.sourceSet.nodes` also has a length of zero when checked. However, the XML Source clearly shows that `<sourceSet>` has a child `<source name="SpecsIn">`.

I'm not sure what further troubleshooting I can do at this point. I've triple checked my connection and it will populate bound fields if the connection delay is set to "off".  I need to do more complicated lookups that require javascript and SQL queries, though, so I need to be able to reference the connections via the scripting object model.

Thanks for anything you can recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK well I feel silly. I contacted Adobe expert Thom Parker [here](http://answers.acrobatusers.com/ViewQuestion.aspx?action=rateAnswer&questionId=199347&answerId=199373&rating=1&action=showComments&commentPostId=199373#postComments199373) and apparently testing in the LiveCycle preview mode does not give the full functionality of testing in Adobe Acrobat. Opening the form directly in Acrobat allows the correct functioning of the Javascript.

Anyway, hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xfa.connectionSet` to access connection details. Also use `xfa.dataset` to access data through data connections.

Comment: I thought connectionSet was for web services, ie WSDL connections. I'm using an OLEDB connection. Trying to use connectionSet with my current OLEDB connection results in a xfa.connectionSet is undefined error. In the XML document, the connection is listed under sourceSet, not connectionData. Thank you for the suggestion though.